# Recursive function not stopping?

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I created a recursive function to find a key-value in a multidimensional array

Function:

```
 public function find_key_recursive($haystack, $needle) {
    foreach($haystack as $key=>$value) {
        if(is_array($value)){
            $this->find_key_recursive($value, $needle);
        } else if($key === $needle) {
            return $value;
        }
    }
}
```

(Part of) Array:

```
$oLayoutProperties = 
Array
(
[header] => Array
    (
        [logo_float] => left
        [logo_upload] => http://placehold.it/150x100&text=afbeelding
        [logo_margin_top] => 0
        [searchbar_toggle] => false
        [language_toggle] => false
        [color] => 0
        [font_size] => 12
        [background_color] => 0
    )

[menu] => Array
    (
        [menu_type] => full
        [menu_align] => left
        [menu_position_toggle] => false
        [menuheight] => Array
            (
                [bar_height] => 0
            )

        [color] => 0
        [font_size] => 12
        [text_transform] => like_pagetitle
        [background_color_hover] => 0
        [color_hover] => 0
    )

[submenu] => Array
    (
        [color] => 0
        [font-size] => 12
        [item_height] => 0
        [item_width] => 0
        [text-transform] => like_pagetitle
        [background_color] => 0
        [background_color_hover] => 0
        [color_hover] => 0
    )
)
```

I call the function as following:

```
$oElement_controller->find_key_recursive($oLayoutProperties, 'logo_float');
```

I validated (using echo's) that the key 'logo_float' indeed gets found, but I don't seem to be able to cancel the recursive function?

I tried the following:

- return false;
- break;

None of the above seem to work.
How do you stop a recursive function?

Comment: You're not `return`'ing the recursive calls anywhere. I'd also check if `array_key_exists` before looping over every element in the array. If it does, simply return `$haystack[$needle]` without the loop. If the key _does_ exist, but its value is `null`, your function will simply return `null` as if the key weren't found. You need to think of a way to distinguish between null values and keys not being found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `static` variable to remember the *status* between multiple function calls. It makes the function remember the value of the given variable (`$needle_value` in this example) between multiple calls.

```
public function find_key_recursive($haystack, $needle){
    static $needle_value = null;
    if($needle_value != null){
        return $needle_value;
    }
    foreach($haystack as $key=>$value) {
        if(is_array($value)){
            $this->find_key_recursive($value, $needle);
        } else if($key === $needle) {
            $needle_value = $value;
            return $needle_value;
        }
    }
}
```

This function finally returns `$needle_value`, which is your desired needle in the haystack.

Comment: Or you could pass `$needle_value` as a third optional argument to the recursion. This might read better for some maintenance developers as they won't need to understand statics.

Comment: @kojiro Oh yes, now I got your point. With third optional parameter it would become even easy. Good point. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public function find_key_recursive($haystack, $needle) {
    foreach($haystack as $key=>$value) {
        if(is_array($value)){
            var $found = $this->find_key_recursive($value, $needle);
            if ($found){
                return $found;
            }
        } else if($key === $needle) {
            return $value;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I haven't touched PHP in a while, but something like this will probably work.

Comment: OK, this is a better answer than mine. 1 thing though: `var $found =` should be just `$found =`

Comment: Why should the OP try this? A *good answer* will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Thanks for your 'rusty' PHP, it's better than mine! Thanks to your example I understood what i was missing!

Answer (score 0):

You can put the result in a variable passed by reference, like this:

```
public function find_key_recursive($haystack, $needle, &$found) {
    foreach($haystack as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $this->find_key_recursive($value, $needle, $found);
        } else if($key === $needle) {
            $found = $value;
            return;
        }
    }
}

$found = false;
$oElement_controller->find_key_recursive($oLayoutProperties, 'logo_float', $found);
if ($found !== false) {
    // found!
}
```